# How to UPSERT multiple rows with same conflict_target in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis

I have table that looks like this:

```
poly_id | class | percent_value
-------------------------
210     |   10  |    60
210     |   12  |    40
211     |   19  |   100
```

When I create new polygons (e.g. `poly_id=211`) it inserts the above record with help of the trigger function below. Sometimes I need to update the geom of a previously inserted polygon, e.g. `poly_id=210`. The updated geom of `poly_id=210` will now cover three land classes instead of two. How can I write the trigger so that it updates (or deletes) previous records? I have tried

```
ON CONFLICT (poly_id) DO UPDATE
```

but it doesn't seems to work and I guess it is not possible to UPSERT on multiple rows with same conflict_target (poly_id)(?). Also a problem, I assume, that it anyway need to insert the third record. Are there any suggestion how to write the trigger so that it updates or deletes previous records with same poly_id and then produces this result:

```
poly_id | class | percent_value
-------------------------
210     |   10  |   50
210     |   12  |   30
210     |   13  |   20
211     |   19  |  100
```

The trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION percent_trigger()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_name (poly_id,class,percent_value)
SELECT new.id , m.dn,
    ROUND(((ST_Area(ST_Intersection(m.geom, new.geom)) / ST_Area(new.geom))::numeric*100),0)
FROM poly_table AS t 
  JOIN class_table AS m
    ON ST_Intersects(m.geom, new.geom)
    GROUP BY new.id, m.dn, m.geom, new.geom 
    ORDER BY new.id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER percent_calculate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON public."poly_table"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE percent_trigger();
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be an `UPDATE` rather than an `INSERT` in the trigger function?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It is more often that I create new polygons and for those I think `INSERT` is appropriate. But sometimes the polygons needs to be edited, and for that reason I was thinking about `UPDATE`. But since the result might be so that it add or delete rows from the previous record (in this case adding 1 row) perhaps `UPDATE` might not help me?

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. I thought the pre-existing rows should always be modified, which is an `UPDATE` in SQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The question is:
When I create new or edit old polygons, I want a trigger function to calculate the different land cover class areas in percentage that the polygon cover. When adding new, it works fine, but when editing an old one and save it, both the old and the new records for poly_id are stored in database. I would like only the last one to be in database.

I'll update the question to be more clear. Thank you!